# How to make more descriptive error log messages in Protractor (typescript)

Tags: typescript, testing, error-handling, protractor

We are running Protractor (written in typescript) against a production website. Does anyone know how to output some log messages when the Protractor test fails? All I have now is basically, just a YES/NO message, something like this:

```
10) Query page accuracy test. Comparison of page data to data extracted from excel. Test begins...
  Message:
    Expected false to be truthy.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at C:\xampp\htdocs\kap\frontend\src\app\qa\qa.js:147:103
        at step (C:\xampp\htdocs\kap\frontend\src\app\qa\qa.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (C:\...
```

etc.
this is the line in which we test:

```
expect(htmlValue == excelValue || (htmlValue === "0" && excelValue == "NaN")).toBeTruthy();
```

How to add a more descriptive message when a test fails? Thanks anyone, I am very new in Protractor, but I have done QA automation tests before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the proposed solutions MAY work, its not a good practice to use them, simply because it requires more typing and not readable code

The two options OFFICIALLY supported by default framework, which is Jasmine, are:

1. For Protractor 6+ you can use built in method [.withContext()](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#withContext)
   Unfortunately, there is no much documentation provided be Jasmine team. But the general syntax is `expect(true).withContext("your description").toBe(false);` and can be used against any Jasmine assertion, not only `.toBeTruthy()`
2. For Protractor version < 6, there is undocumented feature when every assertion takes two arguments - first is expected value, second - message on failure. For instance

`expect("first value").toBe("second value", "verification of some values")`

results in failure with following message

`- Expected 'first value' to be 'second value', 'verification of some values'.`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a description in `ToBeTruthy` like that:

```
expect(htmlValue == excelValue || (htmlValue === "0" && excelValue == "NaN")).toBeTruthy("description why I checked this")
```

If you like you could display failing test values like this:

```js
expect(
  htmlValue == excelValue || (htmlValue === '0' && excelValue == 'NaN'),
).toBeTruthy(
  `HTML differ form Excel. HTML: ${htmlValue}; Excel: ${excelValue}`,
);
```

Pretty much any jasmine `Matchers` accepts an `expectationFailOuput`param:

```js
toBe(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toEqual(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toMatch(expected: string | RegExp | Promise<string | RegExp>, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeDefined(expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeUndefined(expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeNull(expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeTruthy(expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeFalsy(expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toContain(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeLessThan(expected: number | Promise<number>, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeLessThanOrEqual(expected: number | Promise<number>, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeGreaterThan(expected: number | Promise<number>, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(expected: number | Promise<number>, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
toBeCloseTo(expected: number | Promise<number>, precision?: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
```

You will find Matchers definition in [jasminewd2 depot](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/blob/jasminewd2/spec/%40types_jasminewd2.d.ts#L22)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom message almost in all jasmine matchers e.g

`expect(true).toBe(true, "This will be shown if the expectation will fail")`

```
expect(htmlValue == excelValue || (htmlValue === "0" && excelValue == "NaN")).toBeTruthy(`Expected ${excelValue}` but got ${htmlValue });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.